# remove the 'x' in people picker (in chrome and firefox)

Tags: custom-form, people-picker, chrome, firefox

I have a test form on a SharePoint site provided with some JavaScript code which shows how to disable and grey out sections in a form.  I am trying to remove the 'x' in the people picker section using the following code:

```
    //hide x image
    $(".sp-peoplepicker-delImage").hide();
```

Currently this code works perfectly fine in Internet Explorer/Edge as can be seen in the following screenshot:

[image: Code works in IE]

It does not remove it in chrome though, as can be seen below:

[image: Code does not work in chrome/firefox]

Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

Try with `css()` instead.

```
$(".sp-peoplepicker-delImage").css('display','none');
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and that didn't seem to work, I also tried tried using: ('visibility', 'hidden') and this didnt work either

Comment: Are you setting the field programmatically? If possible, add the rest of your code or debug using F12 console!